# Flex 4 ItemRenderer Question

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a DataGroup with a Custom ItemRenderer. Within the itemrenderer, there are 2 states. normal and hovered. I have a <s:Group> within the itemrenderer that shows a bunch of data but i only want to be shown when hovered so I can do includeIn="hovered" which is good.

the problem is the x,y position of this group needs to be outside the bounds of the container itself. much like a tooltip only that this is not a tooltip.

whatever i do, it stays within the bounds of the datagroup. any ideas? or am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are describing sounds an awful lot like a tooltip/datatip.  Why not create your own tooltip skin and assign it to your renderer instead of re-inventing tooltips?

EDIT: Based on the comment below, the approach I would consider is to show a custom skinned Panel or ToolTip when entering the hovered state using the PopUpManager.addPopUp method.  After adding it, then position it where ever you like.  You'll probably need to change the local coordinates to the global coordinates when moving your popup.  Then call PopUpManager.removePopUp when exiting the hovered state.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought about that but I dont want this to be shows based on the position of your mouse. It needs to be at a fixed position always. Also, tooltip would always show if the mouse is over the area whereas I control it via different States under different conditions.